# GPIO values always default to logic 1, is that normal?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, circuit

I've got a Raspberry Pi Zero W v1.1 set up today and I've been trying GPIO's.  Got them (I'll refer to GPIO #3) to output between 3.3v to 0.05v on command using `echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio3/value` with direction OUT and got them to read in logic 1 to 0 by connecting pin #7 (GPIO #3) to a ground (will replace with a sensor later on) with direction IN.

My question is: Would you consider this normal that the Raspberry Pi defaults to logic 1 as soon as you enable the export? `echo 3 > /sys/class/gpio/export`

Can somebody elaborate on why this is? Also, why is this exactly the opposite of this guy's scenario: [Reading a sysfs GPIO input pin (direction as "in") always print a fixed value (0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751674/reading-a-sysfs-gpio-input-pin-direction-as-in-always-print-a-fixed-value-0)

Kthx

Comment: The output has to be a valid logic state.  Why are you trying to compare the output state to a question about input state?  A pin can be pulled up or down to affect the floating/undriven input.

Comment: You misunderstood my question: It's both about input and output, I mean regardless of the direction, it defaults to value=1: if I set the direction to OUT, it defaults to value=1 and If I set the direction to IN, it ALSO defaults to value=1.  Why is that? Moreover, why is not defaulting to value=0 if there's nothing connected to a pin?

Comment: *"Moreover, why is not defaulting to value=0 if there's nothing connected to a pin?"* -- The third/last statement in my comment addresses that. There's probably a pull-up resistor defined for that pin.  Consult the datasheet or TRM, and your kernel configuration, e.g. Device Tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said there is nothing connected to the pin, yet you read value=1. This is due to internal bias on the input which is weak and can be over-driven by an external circuit if you were to connect something to the pin. The internal bias simply is a large (~1M ohm) resistor to the VCC, so you are reading this bias. Try connecting a 1K ohm resistor from the pin to ground and read it again. It should read value=0 as you were initially expecting.